# What is an iTunes card generator?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I was just wondering what is an "iTunes card"? Also, what is an "iTunes card generator"? What is the use of it and how could anyone get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **iTunes Card** is Apple's version of a *Gift Card*. It comes in a different range of values ($10, $15, $25, $50 or $100) and it can be used to redeem any item of the iTunes Store, App Store, iBooks Store, and Mac App Store.

An **iTunes Card Generator** is a software which *allegedly* generates these gift codes, so that you can acquire anything from the aforementioned stores without actually paying anything.